# What is different between Windows 7 and Windows 10 FTP client?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, ftp

We've been connecting to an embedded FTP server fine from Windows 7 using the default Windows command line client. However, now we are attempting to use a Windows 10 computer. Upon connection it reports the correct server name (it connected), but immediately says *"Unsupported Command"*. It closes the connection when any further command is sent.

The difference is in the `ftp.exe`. I was able to copy the Windows 7 `ftp.exe` to the Windows 10 machine and get a connection, however it does not produce normal text output - I saw the FTP responses, but no local text from the FTP program, including /?

IIS is not involved. The target FTP server is in a label printer.

Comment: If you don't have any additional information then I'm afraid this is just too broad to answer...

Comment: Any differences would be the different between the version of IIS that is being used.  Verify your configuration of IIS is identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows 10 `ftp.exe` sends the `OPTS UTF8 ON` command just after connecting (before an authentication):

```
220 Ready
OPTS UTF8 ON
202 UTF8 mode is always enabled. No need to send this command.
USER username
331 Password required for username
PASS password
230 Logged on
```

The Windows 7 `ftp.exe` does not:

```
220 Ready
USER username
331 Password required for username
PASS password
230 Logged on
```

(Tested against the FileZilla FTP server).

---

Your FTP server is not able to cope with the command. Normally an FTP server should reject an unknown command at worse. Your FTP server seems to close a connection completely upon encountering this command.